# connection between android and pc application using socket

Tags: android, sockets

i want to write an App for Android and a java-program for pc(in my case: windows 8.1) which should communicate with each other using Sockets.
My PC would be the server and the phone the client.

My Server code so far:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestServer {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4736);
            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
                // TODO
        try
        {
          socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In my android app i now want to create an instance of Socket. What do i have to put in the arguments of the Socket-Constructor?
What permissions do i need?

PS:I know that i have to do it in an extra thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need INTERNET permission and provide ip and port as arguments to the socket.

Comment: Can you plz elaborate a bit? I assume that i have to take the same port as in the Server-socket. And what IP-adress? the IPv4 adress of the pc?